# ValueError: Unknown label type python

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I try to use 90,000 rows of data as train and 90,000 as test, but I get following error:

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: (90000     1.0
90001     1.0
90002     1.0
90003     0.0
90004     0.0
90005     0.0
```

but when I use 10,000 as train and 10,000 as test every thing is fine.
 my code:

```
train = data[:90000]
test = data[90000:180000]

y_train = train['is_duplicate']
x_train = train.drop("is_duplicate", axis=1)
y_test = test['is_duplicate']
x_test = test.drop("is_duplicate", axis=1)

LR = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', tol=0.01)

LR.fit(x_train, y_train)
my_prediction = LR.predict_proba(x_test)

LogLoss = log_loss(y_test, my_prediction)
```

the error is based on the last line

thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Check your data is parsed properly before training. Looks like rows 0-20k are ok, but you have some invalid data from rows 20k-180k. Input data basic validation is usually the first step (in your case you want to ensure you have numbers, possible check they are within some range).

Comment: It doesn't make sense in your case to use train-test split as in your example.  You already did the splitting (or at least attempted to do at the top). It's probably not related to your error, I just wanted to point it out. As said in the previous comment, double check if the parsing works, print out the shape of your y_test and my_prediction if they are as expected. Based on the error message it looks like the labels are not an array of values but tuples.

Comment: the cross validation part don't have any affect. I removed it in the last edit!

Answer (score 0):

based on the hints,I figured out the issue. It was because y contained 'None' values, so I simply removed None values from y.

Thanks